# Extending Express Request object using TypeScript

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I'm trying to get the hang of TypeScript and various guides on how to use node.js and express talk about adding properties to the Request object before passing them down through the middleware.

Of course, for type script these properties have to be defined so I tried to do so in a file called local.d.ts:

```
/// <reference path="tsd.d.ts" />
import mySql = require('mysql');
declare module Express {
    export interface Request {
        dbPool: mySql.IPool;
    }
}
```

I then try to call it from my main code file:

```
/// <reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typings/local.d.ts" />
...
import express = require('express');
...
var pool = mySql.createPool({
    user: "username",
    ...
});
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.dbPool = pool;
});
```

But I get: "Property 'dbPool' does not exist on type 'Request'."
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

As workaround you can inherit interface from `express.Request`:

```
declare module 'mysql' {
    import express = require('express');

    interface Request extends express.Request {
        dbPool: IPool;
    }
}
```

and then cast request in your code:

```
(<mysql.Request>req).dbPool...
```

Another option is to remove function declaration from `express.d.ts`:

```
declare module "express" {
    import * as http from "http";

    //- function e(): e.Express;
    //-
    //- module e {

        interface I_1 {
        }

        ...

        interface I_N {
        }

    //- }
    //-
    //- export = e;
}
```

and extend interface as:

```
declare module 'express' {
    import mysql = require('mysql');

    interface Express {
        dbPool: mysql.IPool;
    }
}
```

but after that you need to cast module before call it:

```
var exp = <express.Express>(<any>express)();
```

Comment: When I do this, a 'test' interface placed in the same file appears but the extension still doesn't work. It also generates a "An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements." error in the original express.d.ts file.

Comment: It is a vicious circle issue and I think it [should be reported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues). I found some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but lodash's "assign" method seems to work for me, and might be cleaner:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";

...

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    _.assign(req, {dbPool: pool});
});
```

Comment: Just realized that while this solution will let you assign a property, you'll still have problems accessing it after... so this doesn't really work.