# express: project-local middleware extending Express.Request

Tags: express, typescript, typescript1.7

I am working on a node server based on [express](http://expressjs.com/) and written in TypeScript 1.7. I'm using some project-specific middlewares, that extend the existing express Request or Response interface, but I can't get it completely working yet (without tsc complaining about not finding X in `req` or `res`). I've found other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977047/extending-express-request-object-using-typescript) about this issue, but they are either out of date (I guess) or the solution is not straight forward.

I took a look at the definition of an [existing middleware](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express-session/express-session.d.ts), but I didn't get it working without manually writing separate d.ts files and referencing them in typings/tsd.d.ts. This is my setup:

```ts
// middleware/foobar.ts
declare module Express {
  export interface Request {
    foobar?: string;
  }
}

/* my project-related middleware extends the request by `foobar` */
export = function(req: Express.Request, res, next) {
  req.foobar = 'FooBar';
  next();
};

// main.ts
import express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(require('./middleware/foobar'));

app.get('/foobar', (req, res) => {
  /* tsc: Property 'foobar' does not exist on type 'Request' */
  res.send(req.foobar);
});
```

What's the best practice for extending express' Request and Response interfaces? If possible, without the need of writing a separated d.ts, manipulating anything within the typings directory or using `/// <reference path="..." />` comments.

Comment: you can have tsc generate the d.ts files for your code with the definitions flag. all you should have to do is your code should implement/extend the Request/Response interfaces/classes

Comment: @toskv if I set `declaration` in tsconfig.json to true, tsc complains about the `exports = function` statement, as it is "using private name 'Express.Request'", even, if I add a `<reference>` to the express.d.ts file here. After compiling (using `tsc` or `tsc -w` for watching changes), there's main.d.ts, but middleware.d.ts is missing propably for the reason above. and main.ts is still complaining about missing req.foobar...

Comment: that sounds more like you shouldn't be able to extend express.request because it was defined as private. :(

Comment: but typings for existing express middleware (take [express-session](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express-session/express-session.d.ts) for example) get this working. I investigated how it was working, using `tsc install express-session --save`. It adds a reference to typings/tsd.d.ts, but as soon, as I remove that reference, it can't find `req.session` anymore. And I don't want to modify tsd.d.ts myself, because with the next tsd command my hard-coded reference could get erased.

Comment: you shouldn't have to, don't you have a tsconfig.json and package.json files to manage dependencies?

Comment: in my previous comment, I meant `tsd install`, not tsc. I'm using tsd to install typings of external packages, like express or express-session middleware. that's how I should do it. But I'm not sure how I shall handle my project-local middleware. my configuration (tsconfig.json, tsd.json etc.) let tsc use typings/tsd.d.ts to find external typings and uses my regular ts files as the project, so it's usually already aware of all my dependencies.

Comment: your local files can be imported using the import statement. if main.ts and middleware are in the same folder, in main.ts you can do import {Express} from './middleware/foobar'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99600/discussion-between-simon-and-toskv).

Comment: you need to give it the relative path to your file

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution myself, using [this example](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/method-override/method-override.d.ts) as a reference. My middleware needs to be wrapped in a declared module, so middleware/foobar.ts looks like this:

```ts
declare module Express {
  export interface Request {
    foobar?: string;
  }
}

declare module 'foobar' {
  function foobar(req: Express.Request, res, next) {
    req.foobar = 'FooBar';
    next();
  }

  export = foobar;
}
```

It's even a bit more trickier if you are using classes or other imported stuff within your middleware. In my example, my middleware uses my own "EntityManager" class, which is an abstraction to the database connection (mysql for me). My middleware (it's `middleware/database.ts` for me) looks like this now:

```
declare module Express {
  import { Manager as EntityManager } from 'entity-manager';

  export interface Request {
    entityManager?: EntityManager;
  }
}

declare module 'database' {
  import * as mysql from 'mysql';
  import { Manager as EntityManager } from 'entity-manager';

  /* some middleware-related code */
  var pool = mysql.createPool(...);
  var entityManager = new EntityManager(pool);
  /* *** */


  /* the actual exported function */
  function database(req: Express.Request, res, next) {
    req.entityManager = entityManager;
    next();
  };

  export = database;
}
```

Note that my EntityManager class is imported twice, once per module declaration. It did not seem to work by just importing it above both modules.

**UPDATE**

Having the actual code in a declared module (`'database'` in my case) produces no output in the JS file.

Having that code within a regular module requires the name not being in apostrophes (i.e. hyphens would not be allowed there for example) and doesn't produce a one-function-export code either.

Having the actual code completely out of a module (so there's only the declared Express module with the extended Request) produces correct JS but my text editor can't find `entityManager` in req anymore.

It seems like I'm needed to put the typings (my own extensions to Express.Request for example) into a dedicated d.ts file, where no actual code is present.

Comment: Did you find a proper solution?

Comment: At least I don't really understand the stuff you wrote in your "UPDATE"..