# Adding new fields to a class I don't own in TypeScript without type assertions?

Tags: typescript

Considering the following; I have an instance of an object that I received from a framework for instance the request object of express. When I want to extend this instance I usually do the following:

```js
interface ExtendedRequest extends Request {
  files: Record<string, Buffer>[];
}

function toExtendedRequest(req: Request, files: Record<string, Buffer>[]) {
  const extendedRequest = req as ExtendedRequest; 
  extendedRequest.files = files;
  return extendedRequest;
}
```

This is also the common solution posted on SO. In a review I was asked/tasked to remove the type assertion `req as ExtendedRequest`. I understand the concern and consider even if the type system does checks whether `req` can be converted to `ExtendedRequest` the solutions feels a bit like bending the type system.

Is there a **cleaner** way to add a new property to an existing instance, without massive amounts of code and/or significant more complexity?

I considered creating an ES6 `Proxy` but found the amount of code needed not worth it.

Comment: `function f(req:Request,files:...):ExtendedRequest{return Object.assign(req, {files});}`

Comment: "the common solution posted on SO" please link it

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977047/extending-express-request-object-using-typescript and thanks for the working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to add new properties to an object is using `Object.assign`:

```
let req: Request;
let withFiles = Object.assign(req, { files: 'whatever' });
//  ^?
// Request & { files: string };
```

In your case, that would be

```
function toExtendedRequest(
  req: Request,
  files: Record<string, Buffer>[]
): ExtendedRequest {
  // ^ if you don't write the return type, it'll be inferred as 
  // Request & { files: Record<string, Buffer>[] }
  return Object.assign(req, {files});
}
```